# ORM with a PHP framework. Switch to CakePHP or find some Better CI libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp, orm

I am building a personal multimedia portfolio website. I am more designer than developer but I feel very comfortable with code.

I have actually built most of a solution with CodeIgniter. But it feels like mapping my objects (for projects and project descriptions, dependancies, etc) is overly labor intensive.

I have been working on a project (at work) that uses Cache`. It has inspired me to find an easier way to store my objects.

I want to stick with PHP and probably CakePHP or CI. I am not familiar with many of the 3rd party libraries for CI but if there is a popular well documented option for ORM I'll take it. Otherwise I understand Cake has this included? My only concern is how much extra bloat I add by switching just for this functionality.

Ideally, I think I'd like to use an Object or Object-Relational DBMS where I could just persist my objects as is. But I feel that might be a little over my head.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What's the question?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: 1. Are there good mainstreamed, popular ORM libraries for CI? 2.Is it worth switching to CakePHP just for built in ORM? 3.(EXTRA CREDIT) is there an easy to implement, open license ORMDBS that might work well with PHP and be suitable for my smallish project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and how to set it up with [CI](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/). I don;t know how much you are familiar with ORMs, but Doctrine should be easy to pick up. For CI There is cli controller   that basically builds everything for you from your mapping  (.yml) files. I personally use it only to generate models. But it wil generate table,s models and so called proxies.

Alternatively you can use CAKE-es ORM and use [ORM deisgner for CakePHP](http://www.orm-designer.com/cakephp) (there is also a [Doctrine2 verison](http://www.orm-designer.com/doctrine2) for the "over the head" bit. Don't worry about bloatness. Even if it very small project that you can solve with couple of selects inserts and updates, provided you have time, use ORM  just so you can learn. If time is of essence and project doesn't require then don't use it.

To be fair I don't know where is cakePHP ORM at the moment, but when i switched from CakePHP i found Doctrine  much more powerful.

The choice boils down to: obviously project needs, personal knowledge and time available (if you are not familiar with Doctrine but are with CakePHP i woudl say to stick with CakePHP. Alternatively, if you are familiar with CI but want ORM go with Doctrine. If however, you are short in time, website is small and you are not  familiar with either ORMs, don't use ORM.

Good luck.

Comment: ORM Designer project moved to the new site and new name, latest versions can be found here: www.skipper18.com